# How to know the keymap,font,etc. variables' values used by my current linux system?

Tags: linux, linux-from-scratch

I'm using Linux Mint. I'm unable to find the `/etc/sysconfig/console` file that would tell me the values of the keymap,font,utf-8 mode support,etc. values for my system. Is there a way I could do it? I tried `echo $UNICODE` and `echo $FONT` but they don't return anything. Pretty much a newbie to Linux. Kindly help or guide. :-)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `locale` will reveal some things about the current user's current session, but your question seems to be about something else, possibly not well-defined. Adding information about what you want this for would help clarify.

Comment: Trying to make my own `/etc/sysconfig/console` file, Implementing Linux From Scratch. And I'm stuck here.

Comment: `/etc/sysconfig/` is RedHat-y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  GB locale is not installed by default in the LFS implementation. You can see this if you run

```
locale -a
```

You need to install the locale definition for GB using

```
localedef
```

exec the following:

```
localedef -c -f UTF-8 -i en_GB en_GB.UTF-8
localedef -c -f ISO-8859-1 -i en_GB en_GB.ISO-8859-1
```

This give you the two main standards. Then all you need to do for console and profile is insert the locale code for GB using the process as is described in the book. (I have used the ISO standard in the code below.)

```
cat > /etc/sysconfig/console << "EOF"
# Begin /etc/sysconfig/console

KEYMAP="uk"
FONT="lat1-16 -m 8859-1"

# End /etc/sysconfig/console
EOF
```

and

```
cat > /etc/profile << "EOF"
# Begin /etc/profile

# export LANG=<ll>_<CC>.<charmap><@modifiers> translates to:

export LANG=en_GB.ISO-8859-1

# End /etc/profile
EOF
```

simples! ;-)

hope this helps
Bick

Comment: I've already implemented my LFS. I think I had skipped this file, and gone forward with the next section,as per the advice of members of the lfs irc channel. But this looks alright. I'll accept it,as it will be helpful for other people in future. :-) Thank you.